# Nhibernate insert error (GenericADOException)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, model-view-controller

I'm new to NHibernate, so I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. I currently receive this message:

> could not insert:
>   [NhibernateTest.Domain.Order#5ed0d146-644b-44ff-a080-f8cf3048158e][SQL:
>   INSERT INTO Order (OrderName, ShippingAddress, ShippingDate, OrderID)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)]

I'm trying to do a basic insert to my database, which only has one table.

My domain-class:

```
    public class Order
{
    public virtual Guid OrderID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShipAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual string ShipDate { get; set; }

    public Order()
    {

    }

    public Order(string name, string shipAddress, string shipDate)
    {
        Name = name;
        ShipAddress = shipAddress;
        ShipDate = shipDate;
    }
}
```

And my mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NhibernateTest" namespace="NhibernateTest.Domain">
    <class name="Order" table="Order" lazy="true">
        <id name="OrderID" column="OrderID">
            <generator class="guid" />
        </id>
        <property name="Name" column="OrderName" type="string" />
        <property name="ShipAddress" column="ShippingAddress" type="string" />
        <property name="ShipDate" column="ShippingDate" type="string" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My OrderRepository:

```
    public void Add(Order order)
    {
        /* Open up a session to the database. */
        using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            /* Open up a transaction to the database since an order object will be added. */
            using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(order);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }
```

and here's my AddMethod as well as my loadCfg-function:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddOrder(FormCollection form)
    {
        LoadNHibernateCfg();

        OrderRepository repo = new OrderRepository();

        var order = new Order { Name = form[0], ShipAddress = form[1], ShipDate = form[2] };
        //order.Name = form[0];
        //order.ShipAddress = form[1];
        //order.ShipDate = form[2];

        repo.Add(order);

        return Index();
    }

    public static void LoadNHibernateCfg()
    {
        var cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddAssembly(typeof (Order).Assembly);
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, false, true);
    }
```

I know that the Order-object has the information when it's passed to the .Add-function. So I figure it must have something to do with my mapping?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your session/transaction declared? Where do you commit it?

Comment: I just added that piece of code

Comment: NHibernate handles errors very well. Can you check the inner most `InnerException` and post it here?

Comment: The innerException is: {"There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = Order ]"} System.Exception {System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException}

Answer (score 2):

`Order` is a reserved keyword. For example, when querying for stuff you use `Order by`. Here is a list of all reserved words: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

You can fix this simply by changing your table name and mapping. For example, you could name your table `Orders`:

```
<class name="Order" table="Orders" lazy="true">
```

Comment: It was that easy! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I got error like: could not insert: [RegEmails.Model.RegInfo][SQL: INSERT INTO reg_info (MESSAGE_HASH, IS_INTERNAL, PRODUCT, SERVER, VERSION, MODULE, BRIDGE_LICENCE, BRIDGE_LICENCE_EXPIRY, BACK_OFFICE_LICENCE, BACK_OFFICE_LICENCE_EXPIRY, COMMENT, CREATE_DATE) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]

I had something like

```
<id name="info_id" column="INFO_ID">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<property name="MessageHash" column="MESSAGE_HASH" length="512" />
<property name="IsInternal" column="IS_INTERNAL" />
<property name="Product" column="PRODUCT" />
<property name="Server" column="SERVER" />
<property name="Version" column="VERSION" />
<property name="Module" column="MODULE" />
<property name="BridgeLicence" column="BRIDGE_LICENCE" />
<property name="BridgeLicenceExpiry" column="BRIDGE_LICENCE_EXPIRY" />
<property name="BackofficeLicence" column="BACK_OFFICE_LICENCE" />
<property name="BackofficeLicenceExpiry" column="BACK_OFFICE_LICENCE_EXPIRY" />
<property name="Comment" column="COMMENT" />
<property name="CreateDate" column="CREATE_DATE" />
```

InnerException: Unknown column 'MESSAGE_HASH' in 'field list'

I solved by removing

```
<id name="info_id" column="INFO_ID">
  <generator class="identity" />
</id>
<property name="MessageHash"  length="512" />
<property name="IsInternal"  />
<property name="Product" />
<property name="Server"  />
<property name="Version" />
<property name="Module"  />
<property name="BridgeLicence"  />
<property name="BridgeLicenceExpiry" />
<property name="BackofficeLicence" />
<property name="BackofficeLicenceExpiry"  />
<property name="Comment" />
<property name="CreateDate"  />
```